# Problema con el navegador Egde. Interpreta como link un texto sin que yo se lo indique

Tags: html

Tengo un trocito de código html que me funciona bien en todos los navegadores que he probado a excepción del Egde en Win 10.

No sé porque este Navegador se empeña en formatearme parte de mi texto como si fuera un link cuando yo no se lo he indicado.

¿alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

Este es el código html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span style="color:red">( 983 )2018-04-04 18:20:54  correo@hotmail.com </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esto es lo que obtengo por pantalla cuando lo ejecuto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge tiene por defecto un "detector de formatos" que analiza el texto y lo formatea.

Para evitarlo, hay dos soluciones:

1.- Añadir la siguiente meta en el head del documento:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
```

2.- Añadir el atributo `x-ms-format-detection="none"`al elemento:

```html
<body x-ms-format-detection="none">
 <span style="color:red" >( 983 )2018-04-04 18:20:54  correo@hotmail.com </span>
</body>
```

<sub>Información sobre el atributo [x-ms-format-detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn337007(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>